# Interesting notification - Android

Tags: android, miui

I got this notification from like app, I found it bit innovative and engaging. Is it OS specific? How to implement any direction/reference

Kindly see the reference for notification image below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the notification but we can show a system alert window it will be similar to this